# Why My Code is working perfectly without the using of synchronization ..?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, synchronization, cpu

i am facing something confusion with my code behavior in my operation system .. 
You all now that there is a lot of ways to make a synchronization for multi-threading in order to get the right value no matter what !

so how come I am always get the right value Without using the a synchronized way ??? !!!

for example look into the below code

In regular behavior the below Program should terminated after a few second .. as there are ten threads accessing the very same variable and increment it by one .. and that should lead to have a value of count other than 100000 in some cases .. and that will stop the loop .. I am running this code over 20 Minutes .. and it worked perfectly ..

can anyone tell me what is going on :D ??

my operation system is windows 7 and I am using eclipse Kepler .. the JVM is 8 .. and my CPU  is not Dual Core .. it's a regular solo .. with 2.4 GHZ  ...

```
public class Worker {
    int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Worker().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        do {
            count = 0;
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread5 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread6 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread7 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread8 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread9 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread thread10 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            });

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            thread4.start();
            thread5.start();
            thread6.start();
            thread7.start();
            thread8.start();
            thread9.start();
            thread10.start();

            try {
                thread1.join();
                thread2.join();
                thread3.join();
                thread4.join();
                thread5.join();
                thread6.join();
                thread7.join();
                thread8.join();
                thread9.join();
                thread10.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
        } while (count == 100000);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @wrongAnswer: Incrementing a variable from multiple threads without anything to ensure that the increment is atomic or that it operates on the latest value of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code and it terminates immediately after one iteration on my system! (So I've proven that it is incorrect by just one simple run - you can't prove that it is correct event when you run it forever).

That's the back-stabbing character of concurrency: You can't even rely on incorrect code to fail.

I assume that your single core system might be the 'problem': Your threads do not really run in parallel, instead they run sequentially, so the expected race conditions do not occur.

Comment: That's also what I think the problem .. that the expected race conditions do not occur .. because it is a single core system .. 
thanks dude .. !

Comment: @Waseem: even on a single core system it *could* go wrong, due to preemption. It'll be a mixture of that, the memory model, and the JIT-compiled code.

Comment: @JonSkeet so what is exactly happened then ? I ran than code for 20 minutes and it didn't terminate ..

Comment: @Waseem: As I say, on your system everything just happens to make it work. There's just no guarantee that it will.

Comment: Note:  While it is much harder for a concurrency bug to reveal itself on a single-core system it is not impossible.  For example, one thread could be preempted in between reading and updating the count variable.  But since your loops are merely counting up to 10,000, it is quite likely that each thread is finishing the whole loop before the next thread gets to run.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your JVM happens to have generated code where `count++` *is* JIT-compiled into an atomic operation... even though it's not *guaranteed* to... and your computer's memory model isn't as lax as it could be.

It's still unsafe - it's just that you happen to be getting away with it on your architecture.